# Problemas de falha de autenticação de usuario GAPI

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Pessoal alguém já teve problemas com esse erro, estou usando o GAPI para gerar alguns relatórios, e começou apresentar esse problema, já verifiquei senha da conta entre outros detalhes, e aparentemente está tudo correto.

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps "'

Answer (score 0):

Se eu não me engano essa forma deixou de ser suportada pela Google utilizando GAPI.